YouTube API fails to list or insert caption for unlisted videos: videoNotFound
I am using the YouTube API to manage captions, and some of the videos are unlisted. While I can successfully retrieve video information using the video.list service for those unlisted videos, I am encountering issues when trying to use the caption.list or caption.insert services.
The API returns the following error:
videoNotFound: The video identified by the videoId parameter could not be found.

The videoId is correct since I can access the video directly in a browser and retrieve its information using the YouTube API's video.list service. The unidentified error only appears when using the caption services.

This error usually happens if the API user doesn’t have permission to manage captions for unlisted videos. Make sure you have the right OAuth scope (youtube.force-ssl) and that the authenticated account owns the video. Also, check your API quotas and try again later if it's a temporary service issue.
